# Right place to call the Set Tracking State

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design

Which is the right place to Set Tracking State for an entity while following Domain Driven Design principles?

Should we set this in a property change event OR is it right to set it in the services modifying this object.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this ? Can you elaborate on the overall context ? Do you share entities across multiple tiers ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you've added the Domain-Driven Design tag, **so this is not a general C#, EF or OO answer**, I would recommend keeping your domain entities separate from the "entities" generated by EF.  The best way to do this is to allow your repositories to accept and return domain entities and keep the EF data "entities" hidden inside the persistence layer.

I know this takes away 95% of the perceived "goodness" you get from using an ORM, but this would be the Domain-Driven Design way of ensuring your domain model is free to evolve on its own and isn't polluted by your persistence concerns.

So to answer your question, the question of self tracking entities being set to true or false should be irrelevant.